# Genymotion - Select path

Tags: android, genymotion, genymotion-gps

I installed genymotion plugin in Android studio. When I click on genymotion icon, I was asked to select the path to the genymotion folder. Normally where is genymotion exists on Windows? I am bit confused. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

To precise the previous answer, here is the default genymotion folder on windows: `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`

You have to enter it inside the Android Studio settings, under Genymotion section.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you install it from android studio and there is genymotion icon it is not enough. You have to install genymotion by creating a user account. Follow [this guide line](https://www.genymotion.com/assets/doc/Genymotion-2.3.1-User-Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can select the path during installation , But if you kept the default path , Its normally in your programs drive (C drive).

Use this link for more info --> http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/